# Javascript - calculate distance between latlng as percentage

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map. Within the map I have a bounding box. Within that box, I have a series of points. I need a function to express the position of the point with respect to the bounds - ie it is 25% from the top of the box, 15% from the left.

I've tried countless (been at it all day) different formulae, with no result.

I thought this would work (pseudo code):

```
var y = ((point.latitude - ne.latitude) / (sw.latitude - ne.latitude)) * boundingboxheight
```

Comment: equation looks fine. What happens if you console.log the vars before? (am wondering if you have a type problem (rads vs degrees or string vs float)

Comment: how do you express `boundingboxheight` (what's the unit)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have to convert degrees to radians and convert this to miles or km using radius of earth at equator to do distance calculations.

But in this case you can just use the degrees as they are. Using the following values `pointLat` is 25% below `neLat`.

```
var neLat = 62;
var swLat = 58;
var pointLat = 61;

var y = ((neLat - pointLat)/(neLat - swLat))*100;
```